# Recognizing when sidebar is active or not

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, sidebar

I want to use javaScript to recognize when a sidebar is classed "active" or not.  I'm using bootstraps' sidebar toggle button, which when clicked, assigns a class of "active" to the sidebar.

```
<button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info" style="font-family:'Poppins'; position:absolute; z-index:9; margin-left:7vh; margin-top:2vh;font-size: 1.5em">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></span> Filter
                </button>
```

The CSS:

```
    #sidebar {
    background: #202020;
    color: #fff;
    display:inline-block;   
    }

    #sidebar.active {
    margin-left: -250px;
    }
```

And, the JS:

```
//Check to see whether sidebar has class 'active'
var sideBar = document.getElementById('sidebar')
        console.log(sideBar.className)
        if (sideBar.className == ('active')){
                console.log('active')
            }
        else (console.log('not active'))
```

To be clear, the active class is only assigned when the sidebarCollapse button is clicked, and the active class is removed when the button is clicked again.  The above code doesn't work.  It only logs 'not active', even when the sidebar is clearly classed 'active' and is visible.  I want it to dynamically read the status of the sidebar (either classed active, or not active).

```
var sideBar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
console.log(sideBar.className)
if (sideBar.classList.contains('active')){
    console.log('active')
}
else (console.log('not active'))
```

Here's pictures of the HTML, showing the two states of the sidebar (active/not active):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can we get a broader context for your JS? Is it running on a listener? Are you running the code in your DevTools console?

Comment: We're going to need a working example. The code you provide works as expected (though you should be using curly brackets rather than parenthesis surrounding the `else` block).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code should work. There are 2 reasons why your code is always showing 'not active'

1. Your code is executed on page load
2. You are fetching the sidebar div before sidebar got opened and the dom object is not updated later.

Move your code to a function and call that function when ever you need to check.

Sample code below.

```js
function isSidebarOpen() {

  var sideBar = document.getElementById('sidebar');

  //console.log(sideBar.classList)
  if (sideBar.classList.contains('active')) {
    console.log('active')
  } else(console.log('not active'))

}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar" class="active">
  test
  <button onclick='isSidebarOpen()'>
Check</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Add the code below to observe the change:

```
const targetNode = document.getElementById('sidebarCollapse'); //listen to the sidebar

const config = { attributes: true }; //listen for changes in attributes

const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    for(let mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
          if (targetNode.classList.contains('active')){
            console.log('active');
            }
        }
    }
};

const observer = new MutationObserver(callback); //construct observer

observer.observe(targetNode, config); //start observing
```

A working pen [here](https://codepen.io/mdsharif/pen/YzzvMxx).